# Converting extent to int is changing value

Tags: arcpy, cursor, extents, iteration

I am iterating to get extents (XMin, XMax, YMin, YMax) of each feature (1 deg x 1 deg polygons). The values of the extents parameters are double precision and display to one decimal place. I need to remove the decimal, so I am converting to integer. However, integer is rounding negative extents up one degree. How would I get the values without decimals and not change?

```
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(layer1x1,['GEOCELL', 'SHAPE@']) as cursor:
       for row in cursor:
          extent = row[1].extent
        
           print (extent.YMin), (extent.XMin), (extent.YMax), (extent.XMax)
```

-46.0 -90.0 -45.0 -89.0

```
        print int(extent.YMin), int(extent.XMin), int(extent.YMax), int(extent.XMax)
```

-45 -89 -44 -88

Comment: This is more of a pure Python question, better researched over in [so]. Hint: `float` values *truncate* when converted to `int`, so you have the option of adding 0.5 first or using `round()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rounding before integer worked.

```
print int(round(extent.YMin)), int(round(extent.XMin)), int(round(extent.YMax)), int(round(extent.XMax))
```

-46 -90 -45 -89